Как в TypeScript описать тип аргументов функции, как у другой функции? Создать алиас, грубо говоря
class Page {
  go (url:string, options: {https: boolean}) {}
}


class Browser{
  private page: Page

  //////////////////////////////
  // alias for this.page.go() //
  //////////////////////////////
  go (...args /* what type? */ ) {
    return this.page.go(...args)
  }
}


Parameters

@Grundy go(Parameters<Page.go>){ } Так что ли?

@АлексейСоснин только go(...args: Parameters<Page['go']>) { ... }

class Page {
  go(url: string, options: { https: boolean }) {}
}

class Browser {
  private page!: Page;

  go(...args: Parameters<Page['go']>) {
    return this.page.go(...args);
  }
}

Тип переменной args:
(parameter) args: [url: string, options: {
    https: boolean;
}]

Документация: Parameters<Type>
